# Spring boot Dbref

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, lazy-loading, dbref

I am new to spring boot and having trouble resolving dbref.
On a spring boot project I am using MongoDB with dbref. I want to create two collections prescription and medicines. Prescription has a list of Medicines.

```
@Document
public class Prescription{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String doctorId;
    private String patientName;

    @NotBlank
    private String patientEmailId;

    @NotNull
    private int duration;

    @DBRef(db="medicines", lazy = true)
    private List<Medicines> medicines = new ArrayList<Medicines>();

    //getters and setters 
}

@Document
public class Medicines{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    private String medicineName;

    @NotNull
    private int dosage;

    @NotNull
    private int [] timings;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I am able to find data correctly when connecting directly to database as I am using MongoDb Cloud.
But when I fetch the data list of medicines it is null.
This is the code I am using to fetch all data.

```
    public List<Prescription> getAllPrescriptions(){
        List<Prescription> p = prescriptionRepository.findAll();
        for(Prescription pr : p){
            System.out.println(pr.getMedicines());
        }
        return p;
    }
```

This is result of the get request (these are two same prescription added twice)

```
[
    {
        "id": "62190186aedad32aa7bec864",
        "doctorId": "621900fbaedad32aa7bec85b",
        "patientName": "devas",
        "patientEmailId": "devashishdeshpande@gmail.com",
        "duration": 7,
        "medicines": []
    },
    {
        "id": "62190187aedad32aa7bec867",
        "doctorId": "621900fbaedad32aa7bec85b",
        "patientName": "devas",
        "patientEmailId": "devashishdeshpande@gmail.com",
        "duration": 7,
        "medicines": []
    }
]
```

This is the result i am getting in terminal after using getAllPrescriptions() method

```
0$LazyLoadingProxy
0$LazyLoadingProxy
```

This is how I insert

```
public ResponseEntity<Prescription> insertPrescription(Prescription newPrescription, String AccessToken){
    List<Medicines> m= new ArrayList<Medicines>();
    for(Medicines medicines: newPrescription.getMedicines()){
        medicinesRepository.insert(medicines);
        m.add(medicines);
    }
    newPrescription.setMedicines(m);
    prescriptionRepository.insert(newPrescription);
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(newPrescription);
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Edit :
This is how my database looks like-

### Medicine Db

[image: Medicine db]

### Prescription Db

[image: Prescription db]

Answer (score 0):

You must set Medicines Ids after saving:

```
public ResponseEntity<Prescription> insertPrescription(Prescription newPrescription, String AccessToken){
List<Medicines> m= new ArrayList<Medicines>();
for(Medicines medicines: newPrescription.getMedicines()){
    medicines = medicinesRepository.insert(medicines);
    m.add(medicines);

newPrescription.setMedicines(m);
prescriptionRepository.insert(newPrescription);
return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(newPrescription);
}
```

and in your entity:

```
@DBRef
private List<Medicines> medicines;
```

Comment: doesn't `id` get auto-generated upon saving or inserting? i tried debugging and it works and saved in proper tables but it is not getting retrieved and when i intialize arraylist `Arraylist<Medicines>()` like you said intellij shows `Redundant initializer`.

Comment: you don't need to initialize it.
just in DbRef, set lazy to false or delete lazy properties, because the default value of lazy is false

Comment: `[]`
`[]`  this is the output it shows after using lazy=false on the entity and using `getAllPrescription`

Comment: please check this [link](https://github.com/mjimani/stackOverFlow-spring-mongo)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but this is exactly how I have written just not on command liner that is in main function. Is this working for you?

Comment: Yes, this is working for me.